# How to count no of items store in row as per the username

Tags: c#, sql

In below table I have two user name and multiple itemid stored response to username. I want to count the no of items as response to the username. 
I have tried so far but it showing some error

```
string username = Session["username"].ToString();   
var aa = dbobj.Carts.Single(x => x.UserName == username);
int count = dbobj.Carts.Where(x => x.ItemId == aa.ItemId).Count();
TempData["QuantityCount"] = count;
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: is `itemid` in relatinoship with another table? if yes then what is the table's name?

Comment: There's no SQL here... perhaps you meant linq2sql?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return with its name as-

```
 var userEntities = dbObj.Carts.Where(u=>u.UserName.Equals(userName)).ToList();
 var count = userEntities.Count();
```

Comment: I am using session from which as per the session only value which are correspondence to the session name only that value are to be displayed

Comment: I want that the no of items should display like
`Name    Details  Quantity
Ashok    abc          1
Ashok    xyz          1
Ashok    nbv          1`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query the send it to your database. Look like this sample:

```
 DataTable dt;
 SqlConnection cn;
 cn = DataProvider.ConnectionData();
 string strSQL = "Select * From HOADON";
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, cn);
 DataSet a = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(a);
```

Comment: class DataProvider
    {
        public static SqlConnection ConnectionData()
        {
            string cnStr = "your database string";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr);
            cn.Open();
            return cn;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT count(*) as total from Carts";

use this query